# MYSQL - Joins and what happened next query?

Tags: mysql

I've set up a database to record the performance of a group of people picking sports events.
So every day around 40 people choose an team or person or horse or whatever they think will win that day.

The tables I have are Tipsters, Selections & Choices.

Tipsters is a list of all those involved.

Selections is a list of all the choices made for each day. More than one tipster can choose the same selection.

Choices is the 'choice' of the tipster  - also shows running totals of current win seq, current lose seq and running total to 1 pt stakes.

My SQL isn't great but I've got enough to do the basics, join the tables etc.

BUT ... I need to be able to do some 'what happened next' type of queries e.g I need to select those people who had a winning streak of 2 (or whatever) and find out what happened next. So if tipster #1 had selected a winning choice on 28th and 29th October, I need to have a query to be able to show what happened after that. I can do it programmatically (join the tables, select those with the relevant sequence, then take that result and select all later selections etc.) but could do with some SQL. Thanks in advance ... sample data below:

```
    Tipsters

 tid    tname
 1      RCFO
 2      DMN
 3      RPNK
 4      WPKY
 5      SSBG
 6      MEGJ
 7      SSCEKK

Selections

 sid        sdate   sname
 1      2016-09-28  MT-name1
 2      2016-09-28  CCC
 3      2016-09-28  BDF
 4      2016-09-28  MA
 5      2016-09-28  EV
 6      2016-09-28  AQQ
 7      2016-09-28  ERAA
 8      2016-09-28  SL
 9      2016-09-28  SHWM
 10     2016-09-28  OM
 748    2016-10-21  MD

Choices

 tid    sid     sqw sqf     running
 1      1       0   3       -7.56
 2      2       0   3       -13.57
 3      3       0   4       -18.96
 4      4       0   3       36.75
 5      5       0   4       -0.33
 6      6       3   0       8.41
 7      7       0   4       5.23
 8      7       0   16      -27.49
 1      88      0   1       -5.56
 2      89      0   5       -15.57
 7      97      0   7       2.23
 3      97      0   1       -19.86

SELECT selections.seldate, selections.selection, selections.rtime, selections.result, selections.sp
FROM choices 
JOIN selections ON selections.id = choices.selid AND sqw = 2 
JOIN tipsters ON tipsters.id = choices.tipid
ORDER BY selections.seldate asc, rtime asc, selection ASC
```

Comment: 1) pls do not ask multiple questions in one post 2) pls post expected results as well along with your attempt to solve the question.

Comment: Edited so it's only one question.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Here's my attempt - not what I'm looking for but I don't know where to put the select for to get the subsequent rows:   SELECT selections.seldate, selections.selection, selections.rtime, selections.result, selections.sp
FROM choices 
JOIN selections ON selections.id = choices.selid AND sqw = 2 
JOIN tipsters ON tipsters.id = choices.tipid
ORDER BY selections.seldate asc, rtime asc, selection ASC

Comment: What's the expected outcome?

Comment: Outcome I'm looking for is rows showing all the fields in the select statement that occur at a later date than that at which the tipster had sqw = 2